# mongodb aggregation: sort if condition is satisfied else return document as it is

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I want write an aggregation pipeline where I want to sort if a condition is satisfied. If the condition is not satisfied then I want to just return the documents as it is. How to go ahead with it?
example documents where I am checking has_presence field to decide whether to sort the documents on name field (each document will always have a has_presence field):

Case 1:

```
Input:
    {
    "name": "microsoft",
    "has_presence": true
    },
    {
    "name": "google",
    "has_presence": true
    }
Output:
    {
    "name": "google",
    "has_presence": true
    },
    {
    "name": "microsoft",
    "has_presence": true
    }
Explanation: has_presence is true, so sorted the output by name.
```

Case 2:

```
Input:
    {
    "name": "microsoft",
    "has_presence": false
    },
    {
    "name": "google",
    "has_presence": false
    }
Output:
    {
    "name": "microsoft",
    "has_presence": false
    },
    {
    "name": "google",
    "has_presence": false
    }
Explanation: has_presence is false, so kept the order as it is in output.
```

Comment: whats your condition ?

Comment: the question is how to sort only one part of the collection? and why you need this? for perfomance reasons? or you just want to keep the old positions in the unsorted part? (the $natural sort)

Comment: No, I want to sort the whole collection based on a field that will always be there in the documents. Added explanation for examples for clarity. @Takis_

Comment: ok but those 2 collections have always true or always false, what should happen if in 1 collection some are false and some are true? or this can never happen?

Comment: yes @Takis_, this can never happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/5p7HOws9l5Q

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      name: 1,
      has_presence: 1,
      sort: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": "$has_presence",
          "then": "$name",
          "else": "_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sort: 1
    }
  }
])
```